# Adding Web Service ASMX to Xamarin.Form

Tags: c#, web-services, xamarin.forms, asmx

I have created a web service ASMX and publish it, it works fine. 
Then I add connected services WCF. Then I start writing code behind in my interface. Here I faced a problem which is 
**Error CS1729  'WebServiceDBSoapClient' does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments**

lets me view my code from scratch to perceive how to solve this issue  :

1- I create a ASP.NET Web Application (.NET Framework), then  I add ASMX web service, I just put Login function on it, - of course that need some classes. I browse it, it works fine and I can access to the database. "Here I didn't edit anything in web.config".

2- I publish this project.

3- I create the Mobile App ( Xamarin Form ), I go to the main project -not the IOS or Android -. Then, I Right-click then add connected service, I put the local host of the ASMX.

4- I go to the code behind of my interface I put this code in my `btnLogin`

```
 public Login()
        {
            NavigationPage.SetHasNavigationBar(this, false);

            InitializeComponent();

            btnLogin.Clicked += BtnLogin_Clicked;

        }

        private void BtnLogin_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            myWebService.WebServiceDBSoapClient ws = new myWebService.WebServiceDBSoapClient();
            ws.LoginAsync(EntryUser.Text, EntryPassword.Text);
```

and as I mention that WebServiceDBSoapClient does not contain a constructor that takes 0 arguments 
[image]

how can I fix this problem
I search a lot I didn't find the same problem

and if there is a better way and easier to connect the database to my mobile application, please guide me. I am a very beginner developer.

Comment: you generally need to supply a binding and an endpoint address when creating a WCF client.  See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/data-cloud/web-services/wcf#create-the-todoserviceclient-object

Comment: however, you will save yourself an enormous headache by learning to use RESTful services instead.  WCF and ASMX are pretty outdated at this point